# Determine source property of DataMapper validation errors

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I’m relatively new to Ruby, Sinatra, and DataMapper, but have a question about DataMapper validation errors.

I know you can see any errors that occur when attempting to save a new row to the database with DataMapper by doing something like the following:

```
user = User.new username: 'bradleygriffith', password: 'not_my_password'
if user.save
  #success!
else
  user.errors.each do |error|
    puts error
  end
end
```

What I would like to be able to do is determine on which property the error occurred. This way, for example, I might be able to place error messages next to the appropriate fields in my registration form. That is, I want to know that the registrant entered, say, an invalid username *before* displaying the error message so that I could place the message along-side the username field.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `errors` object is an instance of [`DataMapper::Validations::ValidationErrors`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-validations/DataMapper/Validations/ValidationErrors) which has an [`on`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-validations/DataMapper/Validations/ValidationErrors#on-instance_method) method that will return an array containing all the validation error messages for the property you pass as a parameter, or `nil` if there are no errors. (It looks like those docs don't actually match the implementation).

```ruby
user = User.new username: 'joe', :age => 40

if user.save
  #success!
else
  puts "Username: #{user.username} #{user.errors.on(:username)}"
  puts "Age: #{user.age} #{user.errors.on(:age)}"
end
```

produces (with suitable validations set up):

```
Username: joe ["Username must be between 4 and 20 characters long"]
Age: 40
```

Answer (score 1):

All the items in the `errors` attribute of your model class are instances of `DataMapper::Validation::Violation` which have a property called `attribute_name`.

Check out [line 60](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-validations/blob/master/lib/data_mapper/validation/violation.rb) of the [datamapper source](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-validations).

```
#...
def attribute_name
  if @attribute_name
    @attribute_name
  elsif rule
    rule.attribute_name
  end
end
#...
```

So that means you can do this

```
user = User.new username: 'bradleygriffith', password: 'not_my_password'
 if user.save
    #success!
 else
    user.errors.each do |error|
        #print the name of the invalid attribute
        puts error.attribute_name
    end
 end
```

The reason this may not have been apparent is because `Violation`'s `#to_s` method is aliased to `message` and `puts` will call `#to_s` on any object passed to it, so when you call `puts error` it actually prints `error.message`.

Comment: Im getting: "NoMethodError at /join. undefined method 'attribute_name' for ["Username is already taken"]:Array"

Any thoughts?

Comment: hmm, do this `puts error[0].class.name` to see what kind of object is in the array.  It looks like a string, but it might be tricking us.  Let me know if you figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following allows you to get the errors specific to a field:

```
user.errors.keys.each do |key|
  user.errors[key].each do |error|
    puts "#{key} => #{error}"
  end
end
```